# How to query total counts across multiple tables where table name begins with <substring> in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write one query that returns the total number of records in a group of tables. there are over 40 tables I wish to query, so to type each one manually  would be a large tedious query. in this case, all of the tables I wish to include in the query have table names that begin with 'PERF_'
So how would i write something that would return the sum of row counts for all tables whose table name begins with a specific string? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not really a "query" but you can achieve what you want to do using a PL/SQL like this :

```
DECLARE
   nbr NUMBER := 0;
   total NUMBER := 0;
   stmt VARCHAR2(100):= 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ';
BEGIN
   -- Iterate over all tables that fit your criteria
   FOR i IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TABLES t WHERE /*t.owner = '#####' and*/ t.table_NAME LIKE 'PERF_%') LOOP
      nbr := 0;
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt || i.TABLE_NAME INTO nbr;
      total := total + nbr;
   END LOOP;
   dbms_output.put_line('total : '||total);
END;
```

If you don't have access to ALL_TABLES, try USER_TABLES.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases, be creatively lazy. For example, you can write a query against `USER_TABLES`, with the output being a single column in a single row, a text string which is the SQL statement that will do what you want.

Suppose I create two new tables in my schema, one with 8 rows and the other with 4 rows, as below.

```
create table perf_1 as select level lvl from dual connect by level <= 8;
Table PERF_1 created.

create table perf_2 as select level lvl from dual connect by level <= 4;
Table PERF_2 created.
```

SQL to count rows:

```
select count(*) from
  ( select * from perf_1 union all select * from perf_2 )
;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        12
```

OK, but how do I write a SQL whose output is the `SELECT COUNT(*)...` statement I just used?

Like so:

```
select
'select count(*) from
  ( '
  || listagg('select * from ' || table_name, ' union all ') 
             within group (order by table_name)
  || ' )
;'    as sql_string
from  user_tables
where table_name like 'PERF_%'
;


SQL_STRING                                                 
------------------------------------------------------------
select count(*) from                                        
  ( select * from PERF_1 union all select * from PERF_2 )
;
```

(well, it won't produce EXACTLY the same text; the table names will be in upper case, but that's the only difference)

Now copy SQL_STRING and execute it.

**CAUTION**: `LISTAGG()` has a limit of 4000 bytes. This approach should work for 40 tables, but probably won't work for 400 tables (for each table, even ignoring the table name, we are using more than 10 characters per table).